# bootstrap carousel - when the carousel slides, auto update active nav-item

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I would need your help:
[here](https://jsfiddle.net/xgkzf25p/4/) (click to see jsfiddle) I've got an auto-sliding bootstrap-carousel including a navigation to navigate manually.

I can navigate the carousel via the buttons. If I click one, its active. But if the carousel auto-slides, it does not change the active navigation-item. I tried the following code, without success. Do you know where the failure is? Thanks! :-)

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slid', function (e) {
  var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
  id = parseInt(id);
  $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').removeClass('selected');
  $('[id=carousel-selector-'+id+']').addClass('selected');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi your on slide function isnt getting triggered. Thats why it did not work. heres a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xgkzf25p/12/ . it worked for me after this change.

the changes made :

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slid', function (e) {}
```

changed to :

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {}
```

Comment: ah yes, perfect! Its working now. Thank you very much!!